# How to check the actions available in OpenAI gym environment?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

When using OpenAI gym, after importing the library with `import gym`, the action space can be checked with `env.action_space`. But this gives only the size of the action space. I would like to know what kind of actions each element of the action space corresponds to. Is there a simple way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your action space is discrete and one dimensional, `env.action_space` will give you a `Discrete` object. You can access the number of actions available (which simply is an integer) like this:

```py
env = gym.make("Acrobot-v1")
a = env.action_space
print(a)                    #prints Discrete(3)
print(a.n)                  #prints 3
```

If your action space is discrete and multi dimensional, you'd get a `MultiDiscrete` (instead of `Discrete`) object, on which you can call `nvec` (instead of `n`) to get an array describing the number of available action for each dimension. But note that it is not a very common case.

If you have a continous action space, `env.action_space` will give you a `Box` object. Here is how to access its properties:

```py
env = gym.make("MountainCarContinuous-v0")
a = env.action_space
print(a)                    #prints Box(1,)
print(a.shape)              #prints (1,), note that you can do a.shape[0] which is 1 here
print(a.is_bounded())       #prints True if your action space is bounded
print(a.high)               #prints [1.] an array with the maximum value for each dim
print(a.low)                #prints [-1.] same for minimum value
```

Comment: What would be the shape of my action space (a.shape) if I have 8 continuous actions each in the range from -1 to 1? I'm trying to convert a python script to tfjs and see that `a.shape` and have no idea what would be the value for my case.